# Batch job not updating child records

Tags: apex, batch, class, developer

I hope you can help me again experts.

My question is, can I still update locked records (*No edit button after submitting the record*) the page is visualforce, I'm not sure if the edit button is just hidden after the status changed to submitted or the record is totally locked.

Here is the code which I created and somehow is not editing the Call date/time of the child records.

```
global class Eisai_Batch_updateAttendeeCallDate_cls implements Database.batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful{
Map<Id, Call2_vod__c> Parentid_Map = new Map<Id, Call2_vod__c>();
List<Call2_vod__c> toUpdateChildCalls_List = new List<Call2_vod__c>();
Set<Id> updatedCallsId_Set = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> failedToUpdateId_Set = new Set<Id>();

global Iterable<sObject> start(Database.BatchableContext info) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Call_Datetime_vod__c FROM Call2_vod__c WHERE Is_Parent_Call_vod__c = 1 AND Status_vod__c = 'Submitted_vod']);
} //end of start part

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext info, List<Call2_vod__c> scope){


    for(Call2_vod__c newC: scope){
        Parentid_Map.put(newC.Id, newC);
    }

    System.debug('<----MAP RECORD COUNT---->' + Parentid_Map.size());

    List<Call2_vod__c> childCalls = [SELECT Id, Call_Datetime_vod__c, Parent_Call_vod__c FROM Call2_vod__c 
                                        WHERE Parent_Call_vod__c IN: Parentid_Map.keySet()];


    for(Call2_vod__c child : childCalls){

        Call2_vod__c pCallRec = Parentid_Map.get(child.Parent_Call_vod__c);

        if(pCallRec != Null && pCallRec.Id == child.Parent_Call_vod__c){
                child.Call_Datetime_vod__c = pCallRec.Call_Datetime_vod__c;
                toUpdateChildCalls_List.add(child);
         }                               
    }


    System.debug('<-----CHILD RECORD TO UPDATE----->: ' +   toUpdateChildCalls_List.size());

    for(Database.SaveResult sr : Database.update(toUpdateChildCalls_List,false)
    {
        if(sr.isSuccess()){
            updatedCallsId_Set = sr.getId();    
        }else {
            failedToUpdateId_Set = sr.getId();
        }
    }
}//end of execute part

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext info){
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    mail.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId());
    mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
    mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support');
    mail.setSubject('Eisai_Batch_updateAttendeeCallDate_cls Batch Job Run Completed');

    mail.setPlainText(
        'Child calls Call Date/Time field are now aligned with the Call Date/Time field of their Parent Call' + '\n' +
        'Thanks!');
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.Email[] { mail });
}//end of finish part
}//end of batch
```

Thank you.
Marion

Answer (score 1):

```
pCallRec.Id == child.Parent_Call_vod__c
```

In this line you are comparing child record Id with Parent id which will always give you false.

You need to change this into

```
pCallRec.Id == child.Id;
```

or

```
pCallRec.Parent_Call_vod__c == child.Parent_Call_vod__c
```

But according to your code I think you need this condition

```
pCallRec.Parent_Call_vod__c == child.Parent_Call_vod__c
```

Also here you are updating child record datetime with another child record.

```
child.Call_Datetime_vod__c = pCallRec.Call_Datetime_vod__c;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It's only one object which is call object, Parent_Call_vod__c field in the child call is their parent. So I'm looking for every child call record of the parent call record that is why i'm compairing.

Comment: @Mariones so you should compare there parent Id as suggested in my answer.

Comment: Yes the Parent_Call_vod__c field in the child object is a look up field to it's parent record. So that is why i'm compairing parent id and Parent_Call_vod__c field.

Comment: @Mariones you are comparing child record id with parent id it will not work for you. Also you are updating value from one child to another you need to correct that as well.

Comment: can you please show me the code instead to understand. just the line that you are saying

Comment: @Mariones pCallRec.Parent_Call_vod__c == child.Parent_Call_vod__c here you are comparing child Id with parent id